# How to add “New Document” to the right-click menu of Nautilus after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, menu

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that there is no option in the right-click menu of Nautilus to create an empty text file.

[image: Image1]

So how to add the *New Document* back to the right-click menu of Nautilus?

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to add the empty text file on your right-click menu for the updated Ubuntu version.

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key or the *Show Applications* button and search for Text Editor:

   [image: Image3]
2. Open the Text Editor:

   [image: Image1]
3. Save an empty file at `~/Templates` with your preferred file name (in my case it is `text file`):

   [image: Image1]

   You should now have a file named `text file` inside `~/Templates`:

   [image: Image1]
4. Now go back to any location you want to add an empty text file and check the right-click menu. The *text file* option should be visible inside *New Documents* on the right-click menu.

   [image: Image1]

Comment: My Templates folder is full of files, but the context menu entry is not there.